# Spring - How can I configure RestTemplate to use toString() method as object serializer?

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

I'm using RestTemplate and I appreciate if can use `toString()` method as object serializer instead of all things.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Not sure what you actually want to achieve. But if you want to send the toString() of an object, why don't you just call toString() by yourself?

Comment: Thank you! Yeah you are right! I don't know why! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet) told, I need to call `toString()` method by myself.